# Macro for (SFINAEd) template function

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, function-templates

```
#define BINDINGTEMPLATE template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if_t < std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, int> || std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, std::string> || std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, char>>>
```

Is something like this bad practice?

I am using this function template many times within the same class.

```
BINDINGTEMPLATE
void myFunction(int x, int y)
{
   // do something specialised based on input template
}
```

For instance, I need to use it in many functions, like this one :

Comment: what is "bad practice" is purely-opinions based. Though, yes it is. Why do you use a macro for that instead of a type trait?

Comment: How do you mean? How am I able to rewrite this template many times instead?

Comment: If something can be achieved without macros, then it is bad approach, since macros have many disadvantages. So please describe what this macro should do.

Comment: I have added an example to the code. @MarekR

Comment: btw SFINAE is good to select between different alternative overloads, if you have only a single overload as in your example there is no benefit of SFINAE compared to much simpler `static_assert`s

Comment: @idclev463035818 The benefit is that you can check (with SFINAE) if the function is callable with a specific type or not. Of course you could also move the condition to a trait, and document that the template parameter must conform to it, but it might be not as convenient.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat not sure if I understand. You can also check with `static_assert`s whether the function can be called with a specific type or not, and often with more readable code.

Comment: @idclev463035818 No, I mean the caller checking if the call is valid before attempting it.

Comment: @HolyBkackCat now I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a bad practice. Don't use macros for something that can easily be done without them.

You can move that long SFINAE condition into something like

```
template <typename T> using foo = std::enable_if_t<...>;
```

And then you can write simply:

```
template <typename T, typename = foo<T>>
void myFunction(int x, int y)
```

Alternatively, you could put the condition into a `constexpr` function or variable template, then write `enable_if_t` every time you use it.

Also you could use a concept (requires C++20):

```
template <typename T>
concept foo = std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, int> || etc;

template <foo T>
void myFunction(int x, int y)
```

---

Note that this use of `enable_if_t` (regardless of whether you're using a helper `using` or not) is not very robust, as the user can circumvent it by explicitly specifying the second template parameter.

A better approach is:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<..., std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void myFunction(int x, int y)
```

In addition to being foolproof, this also lets you overload the function based on different traits.

The concepts also solve both problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same with a type-trait:

```
template <typename T>
using enable_if_int_or_string_or_char = std::enable_if_t < 
                             std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, int> 
                             || std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, std::string> 
                             || std::is_same_v<typename std::decay_t<T>, char>>;
```

Instead of the macro you can then use `enable_if_int_or_string_or_char<T>`. Macros have severe downsides, so the best macro is the one that you do not need to use.

Comment: I was writing something with same approach, so +1 from me.

Comment: @MarekR unfortunately no. You still get your chance to write the answer :P

Comment: When we use `decay_t`, do we really need `typename`? isn't already in `_t` alias?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, macros are distilled evil.

So, yes: (IMHO) is bad practice.

I propose another way (just for fun: the other answers show good solutions) to avoid it.

You can declare a `foo()` (SFINAE enabled/disabled function) as follows

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, int>
              || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>
              || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char>> foo ();
```

you can write your final function using it

```
template <typename T>
decltype(foo<T>()) bar (int, int)
 { }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, int>
              || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>
              || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char>> foo ();

template <typename T>
decltype(foo<T>()) bar (int, int)
 { }

int main ()
 { 
   bar<int>(0, 0);     // compile
   // bar<long>(0, 0); // compilation error
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of trait checking if the type is one of the types you look for:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_int_string_char
{
  static const bool value = std::is_same<std::decay<T>::type, int>
                         || std::is_same<std::decay<T>::type, std::string>
                         || std::is_same<std::decay<T>::type, char>;
};
```

You can use it as a constant at compilation type with `is_int_string_char<MyType>::value`. In your case (if I well understand your code), you can simplify it with:

```
template <typename T, typename U = std::enable_if<is_int_string_char<T>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++ provides many other options to solve this, one should not go for macros(IMO).

For instance, you could make a [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), where you can specify that any of the passed template `Types` is same as `myFunction`'s template type `T`, and SFNIAE the solution.

Thanks to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction), by which this idea can be generalized for any arbitary number of `Types`, with less noisy!

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if_t, std::is_same, std::disjunction_v

template<typename T, typename... Types>
constexpr bool  isAcceptableType = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Types>...>;

template <typename T>
auto myFunction(T x, T y) -> std::enable_if_t<isAcceptableType<T, char, std::string, int>>
{
   // do something
}
```

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4e79hx)

Answer (score 1):

People yelling *macros are evil* are similar to those yelling *goto is evil*.

Since SFINAE until C++20 is really ugly, macros are a good way to make it more user friendly. But, the macro you provide is indeed bad practice: It's way too long.

I regularly use the following two macros `REQUIRES` and `CONCEPT`, named after C++20 concepts, for quite some time already:

```cpp
#define REQUIRES( ... ) typename std::enable_if< __VA_ARGS__, bool >::type = false
template< typename T > constexpr bool always_true = true;
#define CONCEPT( ... ) always_true< __VA_ARGS__ >
```

Two notes:

- Although the macro actually only take one argument, I use `__VA_ARGS__` so that commata are handled correctly when used. Otherwise, people would have to double parenthise expressions involving a comma.
- The `always_true` template is similar to `void_t`, but I wrote these macros before I knew about `void_t`.

Usage examples:

```cpp
template< typename T, REQUIRES( std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && sizeof(T)>=4 ) > 
void f( T t );

template< typename T,
          REQUIRES( std::is_integral<T>::value ),
          REQUIRES( sizeof(T)>=4 ) >
struct BigIntConcept;
            
template< typename T, REQUIRES( CONCEPT( BigIntConcept<T> ) ) > 
void f( T t );
```

- [+] One of the greatest benefits of this macro is: Even people which do not understand SFINAE can read/understand it, but also use it.

- [-] The only downside I found so far is: The macros work nearly only for SFINAE in the template-parameter-declaration place (I am sure there is a word for this).